# Am getting NaN when I try to get the overall sum (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a function that shows the overall cost of tickets. Adult tickets are $25 each, and minor tickets are $10 each. I have a script that creates the counter, and another script to calculate the sum, but whenever I try to use it to count the overall cost (the second script), it doesn't work, I just get NaN. What am I doing wrong here? Console log doesn't say anything.

```
function TicketCounter() {

    const { useState } = React;

    const [counterAdult, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [counterMinor, counterSet] = useState(0);

    let adultTickets = [];
    let minorTickets = [];

    const incrementCounterAdult = () => {
        setCounter(counterAdult + 1);
        adultTickets.push(counterAdult);
    };

    const decrementCounterAdult = () => {
        if (counterAdult !== 0) {
            setCounter(counterAdult - 1);
            adultTickets.pop(counterAdult);
        }
    };

    const incrementCounterMinor = () => {
        counterSet(counterMinor + 1);
        minorTickets.push(counterMinor);
    };

    const decrementCounterMinor = () => {
        if (counterMinor !== 0) {
            counterSet(counterMinor - 1);
            minorTickets.pop(counterMinor);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="ticket-options">
            <div className="option-adult">
                <p>Adult Tickets (16yrs+)</p>
                <div className="ticket-amount">
                    <img 
                        src={'../images/arrowup.png'} 
                        alt="arrow up"
                        className="arrow-up-adult"
                        onClick={incrementCounterAdult}
                    />
                    <span className="number-adult">
                        {counterAdult}
                    </span>
                    <img 
                        src={'../images/arrowdown.png'} 
                        alt="arrow down"
                        className="arrow-down-adult"
                        onClick={decrementCounterAdult}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="option-minor"> 
                <p>Minor Tickets (15yrs-)</p>
                <div className="ticket-amount">
                    <img 
                        src={'../images/arrowup.png'} 
                        alt="arrow up"
                        className="arrow-up-minor"
                        onClick={incrementCounterMinor}
                    />
                    <span className="number-minor">
                        {counterMinor}
                    </span>
                    <img 
                        src={'../images/arrowdown.png'} 
                        alt="arrow down"
                        className="arrow-down-minor"
                        onClick={decrementCounterMinor}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<TicketCounter />, document.querySelector(".ticket-counter"));

function TotalCost() {

let overallCost = 0;

let adultCost = () => {
    adultTickets.forEach(element => {
        adultCost = element * 25;
    });
}

let minorCost = () => {
    minorTickets.forEach(element => {
        minorCost = element * 10;
    });
}

overallCost = Number(adultCost) + Number(minorCost);

return(
    <div className="option-cost">
        <p>Ticket cost: $</p>
        {overallCost}
    </div>
)
```

}

ReactDOM.render(, document.querySelector('.cost'));

Comment: one of your values is a most likely string or undefined. find that value and use it like this { Number() || 0 }, it most likely will resolve the issue.

Comment: How can you calculate anything in `TotalCost` without access to `adultTickets` and `minorTickets` defined in `TicketCounter`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the overall cost you just need to multiply `counterAdult` and `counterMinor` and update the value when these counters change:

```
function TotalCost() {
  const [overallCost, setOverallCost] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newOverall = counterAdult * 25 + counterMinor * 10;
    setOverallCost(newOverall);
  }, [counterAdult, counterMinor]);

  return (
    <div className='option-cost'>
      <p>Ticket cost: $</p>
      {overallCost}
    </div>
  );
}
```